# RSelenium throwing StaleElementReference error

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape this website [link](https://dhs.arkansas.gov/dccece/cclas/FacilityInformation.aspx?FacilityNumber=23516) using RSelenium. I have successfully scraped most of the contents on the page but was trying to get through to the "facility visits" and "facility complaints". Since both of those buttons have a javascript href when I inspect them with developer tools I have been using phantomjs and RSelenium.

I can successfully navigate to the page via phantom but whenever I try to extract the text from the fields using $getElementText, I get thrown the following error:

```
Selenium message:{"errorMessage":"Element does not exist in cache","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate","Host":"localhost:4444","User-Agent":"libcurl/7.53.1 r-curl/2.6 httr/1.2.1"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"GET","url":"/attribute/id","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"id","directory":"/attribute/","path":"/attribute/id","relative":"/attribute/id","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/attribute/id","queryKey":{},"chunks":["attribute","id"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/c0f30500-55d0-11e7-96dd-3b147ee40d88/element/:wdc:1497974074536/attribute/id"}}

 Show Traceback
Error: Summary: StaleElementReference Detail: An element command failed because the referenced element is no longer attached to the DOM. class: org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

and when I use $currentURL and $screenship(display = T) it shows the correct website rendered and the correct link.

I know it has something to do with how elements are attached to the DOM but I am not sure how to resolve the issue in R

Code below:

```
url <- "https://dhs.arkansas.gov/dccece/cclas/FacilityInformation.aspx?FacilityNumber=23516"
rd<-remoteDriver(browserName = 'phantomjs')

rd$open()

rd$navigate(url)

webElem<- rd$findElement(using="xpath", value = '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbtnVisits"]')

webElem$clickElement()

webElem$findElements('css',"#aspnetForm > div.page > div.main")

webElem$getElementAttribute("id")
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably getting a [`StaleElementReference`](http://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp) as a result of clicking the `webElem`.

The `webElem` element is likely modified in the DOM after the click, so if you try to "use" `webElem` again, it is no longer attached to the DOM and is considered "stale".

---

An easy fix is to simply re-locate `webElem` after it is clicked:

```
webElem <- rd$findElement(...
webElem$clickElement()
webElem <- rd$findElement(... # re-locate webElem
webElem$findElements('css',"#aspnetForm > div.page > div.main")
```