# RSelenium StaleElementReference error in lapply

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a link with Rselenium. Sometimes--only sometimes and this is not replicable (cause when I re-run the code, the problem disappear)--the programme gives me an error as follows:

```
Error:   Summary: StaleElementReference
     Detail: An element command failed because the referenced element is no longer attached to the DOM.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

I think this is because I clicked on a web element and the DOM is somehow modified after a click (see this answer: [RSelenium throwing StaleElementReference error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44657998/rselenium-throwing-staleelementreference-error)). In this case, my code is to click on all the "expand" arrow of a weblink so show the full text. But the click under concern here is wrapped in a sapply function as follows, so I cannot relocate the web element every time:

```
  arrow = remDr$findElements(using = 'class', value = "WB_text_opt")    #locate the arrows
  sapply(arrow, function(x){
    Sys.sleep(0.15)
    x$clickElement()
    })                  # click on them
  remDr$findElement('css', 'html')$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))   # scroll the webpage down
```

Answer (score 2):

The selenium reference of the items in the `arrow` list will be refreshed when you click on the arrow list item in your function. That's the reason why your are getting the `staleElementException`. Please get the specific element in the loop using the xpath/get the elements and then point to specific arrow item using the index and then click on it.

```
sapply(arrow, function(x){
    Sys.sleep(0.15)
    x$clickElement() #<== This line will work only for the first iteration.
                     # you will get issue from the 2nd item as the element references
                     # updates, when you click on 1st item.
                     # Try using something like .findElements()[index]
    })
```